# Checking for the presence of a class

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I would like to check if a particular class has been loaded.

```
Smalltalk at: #TabularXSLXExport  ifNone: [ ]
```

This does not lead to a result in Pharo. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the method you're looking for is `#at:ifAbsent:` (not `#at:ifNone:`).

So, inspecting the result of

```
Smalltalk at: #String ifAbsent: [ nil ]
```

will let you inspect the `String` class, while

```
Smalltalk at: #Strign ifAbsent: [ nil ]
```

will open an inspector on `nil` (note that "Strign" is a deliberate misspelling of "String" so that the lookup fails).

**Edit**: As Max Leske points out in the comments, `#hasClassNamed:` is a more suitable method if you're just trying to determine whether the class exists, and not interested in the class itself being returned.

Comment: Thank you. I should have used  the 'Spotter' going for ``ifNone:``

Comment: No worries. I'm sure we've all had those facepalm moments ;-)

Comment: There's also `#hasClassNamed:` which will answer a boolean. That's probably the nicer solution in your case.

Comment: @MaxLeske: good point - if you're after a boolean rather than the class itself (or nil), then that's a much better way.

Comment: @StephanEggermont: Thanks for the edit, but `#String` and `#Strign` was quite intentional. With your edit, the words "will let you inspect the `String` class" would not have made sense. The second was an intentional misspelling of "String" as "Strign", not a typo. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do an extension method for this, or use a pragma to collect all 'exports', or register this functionality. The world menu uses a pragma `<worldMenu>`.Catalog browser uses it like this:

```
CatalogBrowser class>>menuCommandOn: aBuilder 
"Add a custom menu item to the world menu"  
<worldMenu> 

(aBuilder item: #'Catalog Browser')
        order: 0.19; 
      icon: Smalltalk ui icons catalogIcon;  
        parent: #'Tools';
        action: [ self open ].
```

Take a look at `PragmaMenuBuilder` for how that works

In Pharo4 that is the MetacelloConfigurationBrowser:

```
MetacelloConfigurationBrowser class>>menuCommandOn: aBuilder  
<worldMenu>

(aBuilder item: 'Configuration Browser')
    parent: #Tools;
    order: 0.20;
    action: [self new openWithSpec]; 
    icon: Smalltalk ui icons configIcon
```

Comment: Interesting solution. But at the moment I do not find the ``CatalogBrowser`` class my Pharo 4.0 image with the ``Spotter``?  Which package do I need to load?